# How to center items in login page?

Tags: ios, swift

There are a few buttons, labels and text fields for username and password.
I was thinking it might have to do with one of the options in Attributes Inspector.
What can I do to make sure everything is aligned to center?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provided some information as to what it should look like versus what it looks like currently.

Comment: Learn about auto layout, please.

Comment: You should use autolayout features.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use autolayout. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: alright, I will check it out